# A cumulative distribution function is given as ... What is the probability density function?

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function

I want someone to check my solution b y giving me another to consider. A cumulative distribution function is given as:
[cumulative distribution function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERFwy.png)

What is the probability density function?

Comment: Why don't you post your solution to this problem here? Then we can check that.

Comment: Density function is the derivative of the distribution function.  $\frac{1}{x^2}$ for $50\le x\le 100$. $0$ otherwise.